# Foreach custom loop

Tags: php, foreach

I need to reproduce this grid to show :

- **2 products / 1 empty box in the 1st line**

and

- **1 product / 2 empty boxes in the 2nd line**

and so on.

[image]

My actual code does show only one product per line :

```
    $i=1;
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

        <div class="row">

            <?php if ($i % 3 == 0) { ?>
                <div class="projet-bloc-empty col-md-4"><div></div></div>
                <div class="projet-bloc-empty col-md-4"><div></div></div>
            <?php } ?>

            <div class="projet-bloc col-md-4">
                <a href="<?php echo $post->post_name ?>" title="<?php echo $post->post_title ?>">
                    <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID); ?>
                </a>
            </div>

            <?php if ($i % 3 !== 0) { ?>
                <div class="projet-bloc-empty col-md-4"><div></div></div>
                <div class="projet-bloc-empty col-md-4"><div></div></div>
            <?php } ?>

        </div>


        <?php $i++; endwhile; ?>

    <?php }
```

Comment: Why so complicated? An odd row gets 2 pictures, an even one just 1.

Comment: How can i get 2 products in the odd row ?

Comment: Just do another `$query->the_post();`

Comment: That will reset the loop

Comment: Then prepend `$query->have_posts();` what the while does.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe somethink like this:

```
$space = '<div class="projet-bloc-empty col-md-4"><div></div></div>';
$i=1;
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
  while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

  <div class="row">

    <?php if ($i % 3 == 0) echo $space.$space.$space; ?>
 
    <div class="projet-bloc col-md-4">
    <a href="<?php echo $post->post_name ?>" title="<?php echo $post->post_title ?>">
    <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID); ?>
    </a>
    </div>

  </div>

  <?php $i++; endwhile; ?>
<?php }
```

Comment: This will add 3 spaces. I need 1 or 2 per line

Comment: @Suzan Yes, but with col-md-4 only 1 in first line, another 2 will display in next row, and u get 1 space in row, then 2, then 1, then 2...

Comment: Right, i made some changes and its actualy working !

Comment: One last thing, i can't add an `id` with the `$i` number every line.

Comment: @Suzan what id do u mean?

Comment: I think she wants to add row numbers at the begining of each rows.

Comment: @Louys Patrice Bessette .. Exactly! an id (with row number) on each row.

Comment: Ok merci, tout de suite !